# how to implement coustom psd in xml android layout?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, psd

it's first time to make an android app in eclipse IDE . i have PSD file has 7 screens like this :

http://www.mediafire.com/?ks8vt2y0nw6xfmb

how to implement all this edit boxes buttons fonts background etc from psd or png to my xml file and code ?

note1: my psd files has this res :-

Android Small Devices High 240 - w480
Android Small Devices Medium  160 - w320
Android Small Devices xHigh 320 - w800

I'm looking step by step tutorial . ?

note2: i have finally done splash screen .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you convert psd to html before, but it like something like that. You must know basic android xml info for this. I think this tut will help you. It contains more than you ask.

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: no. I mean it is like it. first you will make some little image from psd. after that you manage them with xml or java code in your application. But you must know xml tags or some java. Don't  be hurry. first watch tuts.